# Oracle : SQL : Return seconds between two datetime fields

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

All,  I have read a number of solutions and from what I saw doesn't resolve my issue.  The reason, I have one datetime stamp right before midnight AND I have one datetime stamp after midnight.

Using the EXTRACT function doesn't cut it because the hours/min/sec before midnight will be 86k seconds and the hours/min/sec after will be within the 100s.  The number of seconds should be around 240, but in this scenario it is -86,000+

Here is what I was using, but again, doesn't work for those datetime stamps before and after midnight.

```
   ( ( EXTRACT( hour   FROM CALL_START_TIME ) * 60 * 60 ) + 
     ( EXTRACT( minute FROM CALL_START_TIME ) * 60 ) + 
     ( EXTRACT( second FROM CALL_START_TIME ) ) ) - 
   ( ( EXTRACT( hour   FROM CALL_END_TIME ) * 60 * 60 ) + 
     ( EXTRACT( minute FROM CALL_END_TIME ) * 60 ) + 
     ( EXTRACT( second FROM CALL_END_TIME ) ) ) AS SPEED_TO_ANSWER
```

Answer (score 2):

If you subtract start time from end time, you get the number of days, which may be something like 0.00123 in your case. Multiply by 24 to get to hours, then with 60 to get minutes, again with 60 to get seconds:

```
(CALL_END_TIME - CALL_START_TIME) * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Comment: I tried this before and I get: ORA-01024 invalid datatype in OCI call.  The datetime fields are exact same format.

Comment: Are these date fields or varchar?

Comment: @A.Lawson - Thorsten gave you the correct solution, *under the assumption* that your two columns are of `DATE` data type. What is the data type of `CALL_END_TIME` and `CALL_START_TIME`? **Do not guess**; if you are not 100% sure, run `DESCRIBE [your_table_name]` to find out, and report back, preferably by EDITING your original post with this additional information.